# Publishing App on Mac (Private Usage)

Tags: xcode, macos

I'm too stupid right now... I wrote a small code on Swift, that will help me with my productivity in my work. Now I want to publish the app, but I don't know how. The library of apple doesn't tell me how to publish it for private usage. 
I just need the .dmg or something similar, so I can start it from my mac.

Sorry for this nooby question.

Phil

p.S. I remember that you had to have a developer account for publishing apps on iOS and that it costs like 80€. I hope that's not the case for me.

Answer (score 1):

just go the project list of `xCode` and you will see the name of the app. Use the right click in order to click on "Open with Finder". There you have it.